# how to guarantee not identical objects in hash

Tags: ruby

The Ruby docs have an example of how to use a Hash that I have modified below by adding a third attribute to the Book class, and also a third book review below. You can see [the original code here](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html).

When the class had two attributes in the original code, the hash method that in the book class used the `^` between the two instance values. I added a third attribute to the class without altering the `hash` method and, on this very limited data set, the code still works in that it doesn't add identical objects to the hash.

So my question is, do I need to alter the `hash` method when I have a third attribute on the object to guarantee that identical objects will not be added to the hash? If so, how? (note, even though I read about the `^` I don't really understand how it's working in this hash method)

```rb
class Book
    attr_reader :author, :title, :year
  
    def initialize(author, title, year)
      @author = author
      @title = title
      @year = year
    end
  
    def ==(other)
      self.class === other &&
        other.author == @author &&
        other.title == @title &&
        other.year == @year
    end
  
    alias eql? ==
  
    def hash
      @author.hash ^ @title.hash # XOR
    end
end
      
book1 = Book.new 'matz', 'Ruby in a Nutshell', 1987
book2 = Book.new 'matz', 'Ruby in a Nutshell', 1987
book3 = Book.new 'matz', 'Ruby in a Nutshell', 2015  # added by me
      
reviews = {
    book1 => 'Great reference!',
    book2 => 'Nice and compact!',
    book3 => 'Holy Moly, my additional review',
}
       
puts reviews.length #=> 2
```

Comment: This example is quite regrettable. `^` is a terrible hash function, and the `self.class === other` gives the semblance that this can correctly handle comparison with instances of a subclass, but it can't really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, you should add the `year` to the hash method too, for example, like this:

```
def hash
  @author.hash ^ @title.hash ^ @year.hash
end
```

Or this using [`Array#hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-hash):

```
def hash
  [@author, @title, @year].hash
end
```

Note that it isn't really important how you calculate the hash for your class. It is only essential that you always calculate the same hash for the same input. And you need to make sure that there is a very low probability of [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision).

Answer (score 0):

I like to explain hash maps with a grocery store analogy.

Grocery stores are organized in a way that let's you find what you're looking for without needing to check every item on every shelf. If you're looking for milk, you know to look in the dairy isle. If you're looking for fruit, you know to go to the produce isle.

Isles (analogous to buckets in a hash map) group things together with a similar category (which is analogous to their hash value). It's cheap to compute the hash value of a food item (deciding what category it belongs in), which then let's you immediately rule out most of the store, and focus your search into a small area. Within that small area, you still have to do one-by-one searching of the items on the shelf.

This analogy leads to some really intuitive observations:

- If you add new fields, you must add them to your definition of `#eql?`. For example, if you care to distinguish between butter and margarine, then that should be part of the `#eql?` method. If it isn't, then your request to get butter might come back with margarine, or the other way around.

  - Takeaway: Overly general equality functions lead to false positive finds.
- However, it's not strictly necessary to add those new fields to the `#hash` method's implementation. E.g. both butter and margarine fall under the refrigerated/dairy isle, and that's fine. Since the isle is small enough, there's no need to have dedicate isles for butter and margarine.

  But most times, you *do* want to add the fields to the Hash function, if they're cheap to look up (which for simple instance variable reads, they are). E.g. there are lots of frozen foods, so an isle of "frozen food" is not very useful. It's subdivided further into "frozen vegetables", "frozen deserts", "frozen ready to eat meals", "frozen meat", etc.

  - Takeaway: Overly general hash values disqualify less of the search space up front, lead to more 1-by-1 scanning, and thus lower performance.
- The most important thing, however, is that if two items (e.g. the hypothetical butter in your head that you're looking for, and the real butter on the shelf) are equal, they should have the same hash value (be in the same isle). It's clear to see why that is. Consider if the store had the butter in the produce area. If you were to compare the butter there to the butter you envisioned, it would be equal. That doesn't matter though, because you would have never found it to be able to compare it.

  - Takeaway: If two objects are `eql?` but have different hash values, you can get false negatives (your look-ups can fail to find the object, even though it exists, just not where it was expected).